# Python, Tkinter : insert request doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

i am beginner in python language and sql request. I don't know why but this code doesn't work. It say that my request is not good. Is it because of type of my variable ? I try several solutions and i saw that there is already several subjets related to my problem. But i don't find solutions.

Code of my class ProviderWindow :

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, StringVar
    from GeStock_2 import provider


class ProviderWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Provider")
        self.widgets_provider()

    def widgets_provider(self):
        # Input field for the new provider.
        name_provider = StringVar()
        provider_field = Entry(self, textvariable=name_provider)
        provider_field.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Button to add a new provider.
        provider_add_button = Button(self, text="New provider")
        provider_add_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nesw")
        provider_add_button['command'] = lambda: call_function_insert_provider(name_provider)

def call_function_insert_provider(name_provider):
    new_provider = provider.Provider(name_provider)
    print(new_provider)
    print(str(new_provider))
    provider.Provider.insert_new_provider(new_provider)
```

Code of my class Provider :

```
from GeStock_2 import utils


class Provider(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def insert_new_provider(self):
        conn = utils.connection()
        my_cursor = conn.cursor()
        print(self.name)
        print(str(self.name))
        my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `provider` (`id_prov`, `name_prov`) VALUES (NULL, ('" + str(self.name) + "')")
        cursor = my_cursor.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        return cursor
```

Code of "utils" :

import mysql.connector

```
def connection():
    # function that to connect to database.
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='gestock_2')
    return conn
```

Can you help me please ? Thank you

Comment: Try to construct the INSERT SQL string first and print it out , then you may see what is wrong in the SQL statement.  Also it is better to use *placeholders* to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct the INSERT SQL statement first and print it out, like below:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO `provider` (`id_prov`, `name_prov`) VALUES (NULL, ('" + str(self.name) + "')"
print(sql)
```

Assume `self.name` has value `David`, then you will get from `print(sql)` as below:

```sql
INSERT INTO `provider` (`id_prov`, `name_prov`) VALUES (NULL, ('David')
```

There is extra `(` after `NULL,` .

So the correct one is:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO `provider` (`id_prov`, `name_prov`) VALUES (NULL, '" + str(self.name) + "')"
```

However it is better to use *placeholders* to avoid SQL injection:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO `provider` (`id_prov`, `name_prov`) VALUES (NULL, %s)"
my_cursor.execute(sql, (self.name,))
```

---

Update: Seems like `self.name` is a `StringVar`, so `self.name.get()` should be used instead:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO `provider` (`id_prov`, `name_prov`) VALUES (NULL, %s)"
my_cursor.execute(sql, (self.name.get(),))
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed your answer and took your advice. PyCharm returns this error bellow. However I thought I had correctly put my viariable in type str. ==> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'stringvar' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: It seems like `self.name` is a tkinter `StringVar`, so use `self.name.get()` instead of `self.name`.

Comment: It's work now, thank you

Comment: @Jean-baptisteBriois If it works, consider to accept it as the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I just accepted it.